# I want to insert these rectangles in the PlaneGeometry as many I can but not able to achieve it?

Tags: canvas, three.js, plane

I want to show rectangles as per my requirements in the planeGeometry as shown in images.
[image]

I was able to achieve this rectangle using ctx.strokeReact from canvas 2d as shown below in images.
[image]

Here is the code, for adding 5 rectangle using for loop but I'm getting only one rectangle on planeGeometry.

```
createStroke = (j) => {

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
console.log("j is " + j);
ctx.strokeRect(10 + j, 5, 30, 30);

return ctx;

 }

 let ctxArr = [];
let texture;
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  ctxArr[0] = this.createStroke(j);
  j = j + 2;

}


console.log("ctxArr[0].canvas " + new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctxArr[0].canvas))

texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctxArr[0].canvas);

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 6);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
  {
    map: texture,
    // wireframe: true
  }
);

// planeGeo.rotateY(1);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMaterial)
// plane.material.color.setHex( 0xf7d36f );

plane.position.set(3, 0, 0)
// plane.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2.0);
// plane.copy();
this.scene.add(plane);
```

How to achieve the functionality for the same as first image.
Any help , guidance, reference or suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you are mixing `three.js` into this simple problem...

Going to focus only on getting something that resembles your image.
First if you need rectangles the width and height should be different you have:
`ctx.strokeRect(10 + j, 5, 30, 30)`

- that will make squares
- you hardcoded the `y` to 5
- the `j` is only increasing by 2, that will be on top of each other

Here is a simple approach:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

createRect = (x, y) => {
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 30, 40);
}

for (var x = 5; x < 180; x += 35) {
  for (var y = 5; y < 120; y += 45) {
    createRect(x, y)
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hii, I am thankful .Actually I want to show this boxes inside a big reactangle therefore using planeGeometry now I can use strokerect for the same.
Can you tell how to add it into the scene . I want to add it into the already created scene?